# ASP MVC native helper for ViewModel property path rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Assume that we have `MainViewModel` which contains collection of `ItemViewModel`, like below :

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public IList<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And, I would like to render form for that model, then I have some thing like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Items[index].Name)
}
```

which will produce following html:

```
<input id="Items_0__Name" name="Items[0].Name" type="text" value="">
<input id="Items_1__Name" name="Items[1].Name" type="text" value="">
...
```

and my question is, if ASP MVC expose any helper method for rendering `id` and `name` strings, I mean about those strings:

```
Items_0__Name //id
Items[0].Name //name
```

I known that I have bunch of methods, which allows me to generate property paths by hand, but I am looking for something native, from asp mvc. I do not want to rewrite framework.

I am also aware that presented design is not the best possible! For sure, I would like to change it! but right now I need to deal with it.

Comment: [Html.NameFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) | [Html.IdFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Whats the point of `int index = i;` - as opposed to `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Items[i].Name)`? What is you actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CarrieKendall ahaaa, it is so easy, I do not expect it, many thanks for this!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the htmlAtributes of the TextBoxFor method

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Items[index].Name, new { id=/*your id*/ , name=/*your name*/} )
```